# Get the rank of a user from two tables points earned and points loss

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables one for points earned and one for points loss. Table structures are:

```
Points Earned:
id user_id points_earned date_time
```

And

```
Points Loss:
id user_id points_loss date_time
```

I want to get Rank of users on the basis of total_points at present, which is coming from Sum from Points Earned - Sum from points loss.

How can i get rank for all users by MySQL query.

Comment: How are ranks to be handled if 2 users have the same sum of points?

Comment: Then it can b just ASC order of id of user.

Comment: how is it looking, did our solutions fit to your problem? @webdev

Answer (score 1):

use join and group by

```
select a.user_id, sum(a.points_earned )- sum(b.points_loss  )
from `Points Earned` as a
left join `Points Loss` as b on a.user_id = b.user_id
group by a.user_id
```

Comment: @Philip   expalin better  .. i don't understand

Comment: In your query you forgot the word join.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple points_earned / points_loss rows per user in the tables, you can use this query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81b33/1

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUM(points) AS points
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a.user_id,
            points
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    user_id,
                    SUM(points_earned) AS points
                FROM
                    points_earned
                GROUP BY
                    user_id
            ) AS a
        UNION
            SELECT
                user_id,
                SUM(points_loss) * - 1 AS points
            FROM
                points_loss
            GROUP BY
                user_id
    ) AS points
GROUP BY
    user_id
ORDER BY
    points DESC,
    user_id ASC
```

If you want to have the actual rank as number in the result, you can use this query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81b33/3

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    points,
    @curRank := IF (
                @prevRank = points,
                @curRank,
                @incRank
     ) AS rank,
     @incRank := @incRank + 1,
     @prevRank := points
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    @curRank := 0,
                    @prevRank := NULL,
                    @incRank := 1
            ) AS count,
            (
                SELECT
                    a.user_id,
                    points
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            user_id,
                            SUM(points_earned) AS points
                        FROM
                            points_earned
                        GROUP BY
                            user_id
                    ) AS a
                UNION
                    SELECT
                        user_id,
                        SUM(points_loss) * - 1 AS points
                    FROM
                        points_loss
                    GROUP BY
                        user_id
            ) AS points
        GROUP BY
            user_id
        ORDER BY
            points DESC,
            user_id ASC
    ) AS ranking
```